# Workflow Activities Extensibility?

Tags: cme, gui-extensions, workflow

I'm reviewing the Workflow Activity screen with a customer and would like to confirm what's possible (Supported through a GUI extension).

1. Can we add **custom columns** to the ones visible in the Activities screen (and sub-screens)?
2. If so, does the (quick, type ahead) **search filter automatically work with any new columns** added?
3. Finally, is there a way to add a way to **sort the columns**?

The idea is for the editor or reviewer to be able to see and work on items related to each other (by page, translation job, etc.), review activities by date, and sort or group work by task.

Answer (score 2):

I kindly received the following details from one of our developers who explained you can modify the list data, filtering logic, and styling in the Activities screen. You also have an extensible area to change or add buttons above the list in case you want to change create additional "subtabs" for the activities.

### List data

The list/columns are defined in this file on the Content Manager:

> `[TRIDION CME INSTALLATION FOLDER]\web\WebUI\Editors\CME\Xml\ListDefinitions\WorkflowDefinition.xml`

### Buttons and list control

The files for the Activities view, where the buttons and list control are rendered and styled, can be found in:

> `[TRIDION CME INSTALLATION]\web\WebUI\Editors\CME\Views\WorkflowActivities`

### Command buttons

The command buttons above the list are each associated with a command (e.g. `ShowAssignedActivities.js`) which loads the relevant list data and also defines the filtering logic (including strings shown as a tooltip).

You can find the commands in the following directory:

> `[TRIDION CME INSTALLATION FOLDER]\web\WebUI\Editors\CME\Commands\WorkflowActivitiesPage`

### Extensible area

The area above the list is an extensible area, which means you can programmatically add extra buttons above the list as well as modify or otherwise swap out the commands used for the existing buttons.

**Note**: as a community wiki answer, feel free to add additional information, examples, or clarification.